# Find an equation of the plane containing $(1,0,0)$ and the line $⟨1,0,2⟩+t⟨3,2,1⟩$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, plane-geometry

> Find an equation of the plane containing $(1,0,0)$ and the line $⟨1,0,2⟩+t⟨3,2,1⟩$

I know the equation of a plane is $ax+by+cz=d$ and so I need to find a normal vector or $<a,b,c>$ (I think), which I believe would be $<3,2,1>$

After that I thought I use the point $(1,0,0)$ to form $a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)$ but I can't seem to get the right answer.  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Let $A=(1,0,0)$, $B=(1,0,2)$ and $\vec u=(3,2,1)$. Consider the cross product $\overrightarrow{AB}\wedge \vec u$.

Comment: Bernard before I study your hint, I just want to say thanks for all the help tonight!  I'm taking this Calculus 3 class online and it is hard without an instructor providing some chalk board examples.

Comment: $\overrightarrow{u}$ represents the normal vector, right?

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad to feel somewhat helpful…

Comment: No it is the directing vector of the line, so it is ‘in’ the plane. That's why you have to use the cross product, which is orthogonal to $\vec u$.

Comment: OK, I got the correct answer.  Now I'm just trying to digest what I did.  So I took the point they gave me $(1,0,0)$ and used the position vector $(1,0,2)$ to create another vector on the plane.  I then used the directing vector (which I'm not sure I fully understand yet) to get the cross product of my newly created vector, using the two points, to find a normal vector to the plane.  From that I was able to form the equation of a plane $4(x-1)+6y$?

Comment: It think it's $-4$. Also, you can simplify by $2$.